# Query sorts differently on refresh

Tags: sql

I have a select query bound to a dataset with a specific `ORDER BY CASE` statement. The query is functional and returns the correct data, but the order of the primary key `Ordnum` sorts different each time within the `CASE` statement. Any edits to this query that would make the sorting consistent? Query is:

```
SELECT Ordnum, BrwrFstNme, BrwrLastNme, PrpAddr, PrpCity, PrpSt, PrpZip5, PrpCntyNme, errorCategory, errorReason, errorReason2, userName, priority, 
                     completed, timeAssigned, timeCompleted, notes, flag, week, process, ignoreGISScoreCard, currentMonth, currentYear, currentDay, currentDOY, OrdDTE, sfha

FROM qc_Orders WHERE (userName = @usrnme) AND (completed IS NULL) AND (week = (SELECT TOP (1) QCTrack FROM CloneOrders ORDER BY QCTrack DESC))
ORDER BY 
(CASE WHEN process = 'Manual' AND notes LIKE '%wells%' THEN '1'
WHEN process IN ('883', '885', '886', '887', '900', '901', '902') AND notes LIKE '%wells%' THEN '2'
WHEN (process = '888' OR process LIKE '889%') AND notes  LIKE '%wells%' THEN '3'
WHEN process = 'Manual' AND (notes NOT LIKE '%wells%' or notes IS NULL) THEN '4'
WHEN process IN ('883', '885', '886', '887', '900', '901', '902') AND (notes NOT LIKE '%wells%' or notes IS NULL) THEN '5'
ELSE process END) ASC
```

**Edit**

I did need to include a `tiebreaker` in the `Order By Case` statement. I also created more `CASE` statements, but simplified the `result_expression`. Adding `Ordnum` as the final clause eliminated random sorting within each `CASE`. Final query below:

```
SELECT Ordnum, BrwrFstNme, BrwrLastNme, PrpAddr, PrpCity, PrpSt, PrpZip5, PrpCntyNme, errorCategory, errorReason, errorReason2, userName, priority, 
                     completed, timeAssigned, timeCompleted, notes, flag, week, process, ignoreGISScoreCard, currentMonth, currentYear, currentDay, currentDOY, OrdDTE, sfha

FROM qc_Orders WHERE (userName = @usrnme) AND (completed IS NULL) AND (week = (SELECT TOP (1) QCTrack FROM CloneOrders ORDER BY QCTrack DESC))
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN NOTES LIKE '%WELLS%' THEN 1 END DESC,
CASE WHEN PROCESS = 'MANUAL' THEN 1 END DESC,
CASE WHEN PROCESS IN ('883', '885', '886', '887', '900', '901', '902') THEN 1 END DESC,
CASE WHEN PROCESS = '888' THEN 1 END DESC,
CASE WHEN PROCESS LIKE '889%' THEN 1 END DESC,
CASE WHEN NOTES LIKE '%WELLS%' THEN 2 END DESC,
CASE WHEN PROCESS = 'MANUAL' THEN 2 END DESC,
CASE WHEN PROCESS IN ('883', '885', '886', '887', '900', '901', '902') THEN 2 END DESC,
CASE WHEN PROCESS = '888' THEN 2 END DESC, 
CASE WHEN PROCESS LIKE '889%' THEN 2 END DESC,
ORDNUM ASC
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Looks like you might want the CASE statement as a field like 'SortOrder' and then ORDER BY SortOrder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `tiebreaker` in your `ORDER` clause. If `Ordnum` is unique within `CASE` then add it after the `CASE`. If not then you will have to add some more columns in `ORDER` clause:

```
SELECT Ordnum, BrwrFstNme, BrwrLastNme, PrpAddr, PrpCity, PrpSt, PrpZip5, PrpCntyNme, errorCategory, errorReason, errorReason2, userName, priority, 
                     completed, timeAssigned, timeCompleted, notes, flag, week, process, ignoreGISScoreCard, currentMonth, currentYear, currentDay, currentDOY, OrdDTE, sfha

FROM qc_Orders WHERE (userName = @usrnme) AND (completed IS NULL) AND (week = (SELECT TOP (1) QCTrack FROM CloneOrders ORDER BY QCTrack DESC))
ORDER BY 
(CASE WHEN process = 'Manual' AND notes LIKE '%wells%' THEN '1'
WHEN process IN ('883', '885', '886', '887', '900', '901', '902') AND notes LIKE '%wells%' THEN '2'
WHEN (process = '888' OR process LIKE '889%') AND notes  LIKE '%wells%' THEN '3'
WHEN process = 'Manual' AND (notes NOT LIKE '%wells%' or notes IS NULL) THEN '4'
WHEN process IN ('883', '885', '886', '887', '900', '901', '902') AND (notes NOT LIKE '%wells%' or notes IS NULL) THEN '5'
ELSE process END) ASC, Ordnum
```